# Python: Count number of times a row from one dataframe appears in another

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that look like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Cat', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'David'],
    'name2': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'David'],
})

master_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Dog', 'David'],
    'name2': ['Cat', 'David'],
})
```

I want to count the number of times each row in master_df appears in df1. So the result should look like this:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Frequency': ['2', '1'],
    'name': ['Dog', 'David'],
    'name2': ['Cat', 'David'],
})
```

I tried to achieve this using the following code, but it isn't working

```
merged_df = master_df.merge(df1, on=['name', 'name2'], how='left')
counts = merged_df.groupby(['name', 'name2']).size().reset_index(name='count')
counts
```

Its hard to properly take into account that order of the columns don't matter, I just want to compare both elements in each row.

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you have 2 in place of 3 in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `frozensets` as keys for [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
master_df.merge(df1.apply(frozenset, axis=1).value_counts().rename('Frequency'),
                left_on=master_df.apply(frozenset, axis=1),
                right_index=True, how='left')
```

Output:

```
    name  name2  Frequency
0    Dog    Cat          2
1  David  David          1
```

Comment: This is clever as it elides the sort to establish row equivalency and seems fine given there are only two values per row. If rows had >2 values, this could cause rows with duplicates in different combinations to register as equivalent. For example, I believe a row of three values `dog,cat,cat` would be treated as equivalent to `dog,dog,cat` with frozenset.

Comment: @constantstranger you could then use a `frozenset` of `Counter`'s items ;)

Comment: Yes, you're right (though perhaps not as streamlined as simply using frozenset in apply() and avoiding a lambda). Your use of `left_on` with an array (or Series) is also quite elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can try combining this two rows in single sorted list, filtering and then flattening back into columns and performing final count:

```py
cols = ['name', 'name2']
df1['combined'] = df1[cols].apply(lambda x: sorted(x), axis=1)
master_df['combined'] = master_df[cols].apply(lambda x: sorted(x), axis=1)

temp = df1.loc[df1['combined'].isin(master_df['combined']), 'combined'].to_frame()
df3 = pd.DataFrame(temp['combined'].to_list(), columns=['name','name2'])
res = df3.groupby(cols).size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```python
srFreq = df1.assign(idx=df1.apply(
    lambda row: tuple(sorted(row)), axis=1)).groupby('idx').size().rename('Frequency')
final_df = master_df.assign(idx=master_df.apply(
    lambda row: tuple(sorted(row)), axis=1)).set_index('idx')
final_df = final_df.join(srFreq).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Sample input:

```
    name  name2
0    Dog    Cat
1    Cat    Cat
2    Cat    Dog
3  David  David

    name  name2
0    Dog    Cat
1  David  David
```

Output:

```
    name  name2  Frequency
0    Dog    Cat          2
1  David  David          1
```

---

If you need to preserve the original index of master_df, you can do this:

```python
srFreq = df1.assign(sorted_row=df1.apply(
    lambda row: tuple(sorted(row)), axis=1)).groupby('sorted_row').size()
final_df = ( master_df
    .reset_index(drop=False)
    .assign(sorted_row=master_df.apply(
        lambda row: tuple(sorted(row)), axis=1))
    .set_index('sorted_row').pipe(lambda d: d
    .assign(Frequency=srFreq.reindex(d.index))).set_index('index').rename_axis(None) )
```

Explanation:

- Create Series srFreq to be sorted tuples from the rows in df1 and use these as a new column to groupby and obtain the count of equivalent rows (this is essentially the result data you're looking for, but for all non-equivalent rows in df1 rather than just those in master_df)
- For master_df:

  - Use reset_index() to store a copy of the original index of master_df
  - Use similar logic as for df1 to create a column of sorted row tuples and set it to be the index
  - Create a new column `Frequency` which selects from srFreq the results for rows equivalent to those in master_df
  - Restore the original index.